# How to unit test against gen_server callbacks?

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I have a case where a process starts, sends itself a message in the `init` block, and has a side effect elsewhere of dynamically creating some processes. I want to unit test this, but there is no way to determine exactly when the activities will be complete to make assertions against the mocks. Eg it's *eventually* invoked after starting the process. In scala, scalatest has mechanisms to test items like this but I'm thinking that unit testing against the callback would be sufficient.

Is it considered improper to unit test again GenServer callbacks directly (`handle_info`, `handle_call` and `handle_cast`)?
I can understand that there may be value in the test in starting the process, but that's more of an integration test.
Would it be okay to invoke eg `handle_info/2` in a unit test on a Module instead of starting a process and checking for effects?

Comment: Not totally sure I understand what you're trying to do but this may be worth your reading time: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/10/mocks-and-explicit-contracts/

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I’d say the whole Plataformatec blog is a must for Elixirists.

Comment: @mudasobwa I agree.  A lot of good information there that's well worth the time to read.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci “And God said: ‘...’ and there was light” :)